# defining custom dplyr methods in R package

Tags: r, dplyr, r-package, tidyverse, r-s3

I have a package with custom `summary()`, `print()` methods for objects that have a particular class.  This package also uses the wonderful `dplyr` package for data manipulation - and I expect my users to write scripts that use both my package and dplyr.

One roadblock, which has been noted by others [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1429#issuecomment-152344873) and [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/719) is that dplyr verbs doesn't preserve custom classes - meaning that an `ungroup` command can strip my data.frames of their custom classes, and thus screw up method dispatch for `summary`, etc.

Hadley says "doing this correctly is up to you - you need to define a method for your class for each dplyr method that correctly restores all the classes and attributes" and I'm trying to take the [advice](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/719#issuecomment-108082280) - but I can't figure out how to correctly wrap the dplyr verbs.

Here's a simple toy example.  Let's say I've defined a `cars` class, and I have a custom `summary` for it.

## this works

```
library(tidyverse)

class(mtcars) <- c('cars', class(mtcars))

summary.cars <- function(x, ...) {
  #gather some summary stats
  df_dim <- dim(x)
  quantile_sum <- map(mtcars, quantile)
  
  cat("A cars object with:\n")
  cat(df_dim[[1]], 'rows and ', df_dim[[2]], 'columns.\n')
  
  print(quantile_sum)

}

summary(mtcars)
```

## here's the problem

```
small_cars <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl < 6)
summary(small_cars)
class(small_cars)
```

that `summary` call for `small_cars` just gives me the generic summary, not my custom method, because `small_cars` no longer retains the `cars` class after dplyr filtering.

## what I tried

First I tried writing a custom method around `filter` (`filter.cars`).  That didn't work, because `filter` actually a wrapper around `filter_` that allows for non-standard evaluation.

So I wrote a custom `filter_` method for `cars` objects, attempting to implement @jwdink 's [advice](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/719#issuecomment-108082280)

```
filter_.cars <- function(df, ...) {
  
  old_classes <- class(df)
  out <- dplyr::filter_(df, ...)
  new_classes <- class(out)
  
  class(out) <- c(new_classes, old_classes) %>% unique()
  
  out
}
```

That doesn't work - I get an infinite recursion error:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

All I want to do is grab the classes on the incoming df, hand off to dplyr, then return the object with the same classnames as it had before the dplyr call.  **How do I change my `filter_` wrapper to accomplish that?**  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE:

Some things have changed since my original answer:

- Many dplyr verbs no longer remove custom classes; for example, `dplyr::filter` keeps the class. However, some — like `dplyr::group_by` — still remove the class, so this question lives on.
- With R 3.5 and beyond, method lookup changed its scoping rules
- The trailing-underscore version of the verbs are deprecated

Recently ran into a hard-to-figure-out issues due to the second bullet, so just wanted to give a fuller example. Let's say you're using a custom class, with name `custom_class`, and you want to add a groupby method. Assuming you're using roxygen:

```
#' group_by.custom_class
#' 
#' @description Preserve the class of a `custom_class` object.
#' @inheritParams dplyr::group_by
#'
#' @importFrom dplyr group_by
#'
#' @export
#' @method group_by custom_class
group_by.custom_class <- function(.data, ...) {
  result <- NextMethod()
  return(reclass(.data, result))
}
```

(see original answer for definition of `reclass` function)

Highlights:

- You need `@method group_by custom_class` to add `S3method(group_by,custom_class)` to NAMESPACE
- You need `@importFrom dplyr group_by` to add `importFrom(dplyr,group_by)` to your NAMESPACE

I believe in R < 3.5 you could get away with just that second one, but now you need both.

---

OLD ANSWER:

Further suggestions were offered in [the thread](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/719) so I thought I'd update with what seems to be best practice, which is to use `NextMethod()`.

```
filter_.cars <- function(.data, ...) {
   result <- NextMethod()
   reclass(.data, result)
}
```

Where `reclass` is written by you; it's just a generic that (at least) adds the original class back on:

```
reclass <- function(x, result) {
  UseMethod('reclass')
}

reclass.default <- function(x, result) {
  class(result) <- unique(c(class(x)[[1]], class(result)))
  result
}
```

Comment: I like your last example, though I think `reclass(data, NextMethod())` needs to be changed to `reclass(.data, NextMethod())`

Comment: While it's a nice workaround, it doesn't seem very reasonable for **dplyr** to delete the classes to begin with. This workaround means that every package that uses custom data frame classes now have to add methods for every **dplyr** verb...

Comment: Eric, I've fixed the typo with `.data` vs. `data` (I didn't notice it until I tried to implement the code myself.)

Answer (score 8):

Your new `filter_` method tries to apply to the new class within the definition, hence the recursion.

Following [the advice in the issue you linked](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/719), try removing that new class prior to `filter_` in your updated method.

```
class(out) <- class(out)[-1]
```

Comment: this was really interesting.  When I wrote this I thought dplyr::filter_  *guaranteed* that the internal call got dplyr-flavored dispatch, but that's not enough!  the recursion makes sense now.